# Postfix periodic relay access denied

Tags: email, spam

I administer an Ubuntu Server 14.04 which acts as a mail server running Postfix and was configured following most parts of this tutorial: http://www.pixelinx.com/2013/09/creating-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-postfix-courier-ssltls-spamassassin-clamav-amavis/

I have ports 25 and 143 open to the public use STARTSSL communication for both in and out and can connect using IMAP from the outside without problems.

I have fail2ban enabled (and actually bans IPs quite frequently) and also have configured some parameters to prevent spam:

```
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

The question is that from a couple of months ago, I see this trace in the mail.log every few hours:

```
Apr 23 05:52:08 myhost postfix/smtpd[9727]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 118-165-146-33.dynamic.hinet.net[118.165.146.33]: 554 5.7.1 <gk49fawn@yahoo.com.tw>: Relay access denied; from=<z2007tw@yahoo.com.tw> to=<gk49fawn@yahoo.com.tw> proto=SMTP helo=<xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>
```

IP addresses change regularly, and recipients also do change from time to time, but the sender is always the same. Also, since it appears only a couple of times a day, fail2ban does not react against it.

I understand that the relay is being denied properly so it is not a big deal, but should I worry about this and/or take any extra action against it?

Comment: You can safely ignore it. For the additional security paramater, see [this page](http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#conn_limit) to help server against abuse by out-of-control bot.

Answer (score 1):

These are automated bots (most likely running on compromised machines) that try to use your server as an [open relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay) to send their spam - your server is correctly configured and rejects their attempts so everything is fine from this side.

You say that it only happens every few hours so it isn't really worth trying to do anything about them, the load they put on your server is minimal.

If you still want to block them or if they become more frequent and start to put more load on your server you can adjust your Fail2Ban rules to be more strict, there's no risk of false positives here so you can safely ban them after a single attempt.